# My custom attribute is not displaying in the active directory object

Tags: active-directory

I have create a custom attribute named "language" and affected it to the class "user".

[image: Screenshot of language attribute properties]

Then I have applied it to the "user" class

[image: Screenshot of user class attributes]

But I don't see the new attribute in the user properties

[image: Screenshot of sample user properties]

Replication is done since I did it yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I had to reboot my DC's and they finally showed up.